# How can I reverse to the number without using string methods?

Tags: python

I am trying to reverse an integer number without using string methods in python.I tryed to modify it from an other language but I am doing something wrong.What is it that I am doing wrong?
Here is the code:

```
count =1
while count!=0:
    sayi = int(input("Number:\n"))
    if sayi != -1:
        while number>0:
            newnumber = number % 10
            print("{}".format(int(number)))
            sayi /= 10
            print("Reversing number :{}".format(int(newnumber )))
    else:
        break
    count += 1
```

Comment: You input into `sayi` variable, but check `number` in the loop. But `number` is never set to anything

Comment: I do not understand what you mean.Could you explain it in the code?@Alexey Larionov

Comment: Try to execute the code in your head line by line. When you execute line `while number>0:` , the `number` variable should already contain some value. But does it? No. You never assign it to anything. No line like `number = ....`

Comment: `def revInt(N,r=0): return revInt(N//10,r*10+N%10) if N else r`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Besides what I already wrote in the comments about you using `number` variable without assigning it to anything, there's another problem, that you use floating point division here `sayi /= 10`. Because of that `sayi` gets assigned to a floating point number, and it might not necessarily approach exactly number `0` (because floating point numbers are imprecise, and it may end up a very small number, but not exactly `0`). Instead you better use integer division with `//` operator.

Here's a simpler version for your program

```
number = int(input("Number: "))
reversed_number = 0
while number > 0:
    digit = number % 10
    reversed_number = reversed_number * 10 + digit
    number = number // 10

print(f"Reversed: {reversed_number}")
```

Comment: `number, digit = divmod(number, 10)` ;-)